# Django + Apache - file.open() Permission Denied

Tags: django, file, apache2, permission-denied

So I have the following problem:
On an ivent a javascript sends some text to the django server and there are two functions that should work:
views.py:

```
def log(request):
  f = open('media/log.txt', 'r')
  return HttpResponse(f, mimetype='text/plain')

def modelers(request):
    mod_stat = request.POST['id']
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
    file=open('media/log.txt', 'a')
    file.write(time)
    file.write(' ')
    file.write(mod_stat)
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()

return ErrorResponse()
```

so the user clicks on a button and the "modelers" function is getting the info and is trying to add a line to the log file. But it doesn't work! 
The apache error.log says that

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'media/log.txt', referer: ...

chmod 777 media doesn't help.. I know that I must config the apache somehow to let the django write files, but didn't find how :(

If not under apache it works great(so the url.py is OK), but I need to make it work with apache. The other part of the application also works fine but there are no operations with files.. until now..

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `chmod 777 media/log.txt`?  Does `ls -l media/` say `rwxrwxrwx log.txt`?  If yes then try to specify absolute path to `log.txt` in `f = open('...log.txt')`

Comment: The absolute path did the job.. Thanks!! I've tried a lot of things but didn't think about that cause the error.log didn't say it can't find the file.. Thanks a lot!))